# transaction sent to null

Tags: go-ethereum

I wanted to make my first transaction between my wallets (geth to ledger), so I put my ledger into USB and enter the pin.
Geth was able to see my ledger (eth.accounts[1]), and I tried just a small amount of money to see, if it works.
(I removed some sensitive information, because I don't know if my problem is now in a state, where somebody can get my "lost" money)

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to:eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(<small_amount>, "ether")})
"0xblalbla"
```

Everything went fine.
So I made a larger transaction:

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to:eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(<larger_amount>, "ether")})
"0xblalbla2"
```

But then I realised, that the eth.accounts[1] did not get any value (somehow lost the ledger, but wasn't in sleep mode, it was still in Ethereum app).

```
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1]));
Error: invalid address
    at web3.js:3930:15
    at web3.js:5025:28
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:5024:12
    at web3.js:5050:18
    at web3.js:5075:23
    at <anonymous>:1:14
```

I disconnected, and connected again.
Tried to make a new transaction. (now I know I should have been cancel my actual Pending transaction)

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to:eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(<larger_amount>, "ether")})
"0xblalbla3"
```

Now I have seen, that there are already 2 pending Transactions

```
> eth.pendingTransactions [{
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    from: <geth_account>,
    gas: 90000,
    gasPrice: 50000000000,
    hash: "0xblalbla2",
    input: "0x",
    nonce: 1,
    r: "xx",
    s: "xx",
    to: null,
    transactionIndex: 0,
    v: "0x25",
    value: <larger_amount> },
{
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    from: <geth_account>,
    gas: 90000,
    gasPrice: 52000000000,
    hash: "0xblalbla3",
    input: "0x",
    nonce: 2,
    r: "xx",
    s: "xx",
    to: <ledger_account>,
    transactionIndex: 0,
    v: "0x26",
    value: <larger_amount> }]
```

So I looked for a solution on the internet, and tried to get rid of the Pending transactions.

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to:eth.accounts[1], value: 0, gasPrice: 57720000000, gasLimit: 24000, nonce: 2});
"0xblabla4"
```

I successfully removed the nonce 2, but in the meantime the nonce 1 became success.
It was sent to null, and that created a contract.

How can I get the money back to my wallet address, if there is a way?
If there is no sensitive information, then I can put all the information here, if it is needed to recover my eth.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have deployed an empty contract which was asigned the ether you sent. Immediately there's nothing you can do to recover your funds from that empty contract.

Although there is a proposal [EIP 156](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/156) to recover ether frozen from certain type of contracts. One of them being empty contracts.